# Improving texture bakes with smoke domains

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I am trying to bake my smoke simulation into a texture of a low-poly mesh, built around my smoke domain. And for some reason the final bake is not following conventional bake rules, just see for yourself:

[image]

Instead of smoke pixels being smoothly spread across the entire texture, I get these four distinct quadrants. Is there any way to tell the renderer to do things properly?

I created an almond-shaped mesh with a red emissive material and baked it onto the same low poly mesh. This is how the result should look like:

[image]

Obviously it's a rough example, if it was a proper smoke it would have texture and stuff. Only that texture would not be made out of 4 separate images like with the bake I get.

Comment: Is that conical cylinder your domain?

Comment: No, the Domain is the cube inside the cylinder. Good hint dude, thank you, the domain is modifiable, I will try it now.

Comment: Let us know if it worked!

Comment: Nah, modifying the domain does nothing. Sad. Moreover it does not change  the shape - it's always the cube. Still your hint is very good. Now I have some idea about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Can you share a hint image so we can know what your result should be!

Comment: May be try every possible way! Actually I didn't bake something previously. As it was about smoke simu. so I just :)

Comment: See the update. And I did try every possible way already. :(

Comment: You need pixelated smoke right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101198/discussion-between-cubrman-and-yash).